# MediaWiki SVG thumbnailing

Tags: svg, thumbnails, mediawiki

My Wiki has had repeated issues with thumbnailing. Using ImageMagick I received this thumbnailing result:

[image]

When I changed

`$wgSVGConverter = 'librsvg'`

and (keeping in mind I installed librsvg using cygwin)

`$wgSVGConverterPath = 'C:\cygwin64\usr\include\librsvg-2.0\librsvg';`

no thumbnailing occurred, e.g.,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions to this problem.

## Thumbnailing

For 64-bit Windows 7, like what I am running the best solution is to
add this to `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgSVGConverters = array(
    'ImageMagick' => 'convert -resize $width $input $output',
    'Inkscape' => '"/Program Files (x86)/Inkscape/inkscape.com" -z -w $width -f $input -e $output',
);
```

### ImageMagick

Add this to `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgSVGConverter = 'ImageMagick';
```

### Inkscape

Add this to `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgSVGConverter = 'Inkscape';
```

## Client-side rendering of SVG

Install the NativeSvgHandler extension (http://mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:NativeSvgHandler) which will embed SVGs into the article and send them of to one's web-browser for client-side rendering.